# Update a Null column with conditional split null check

Tags: ssis

I am using conditional split to check if a row has changed or new. If new row insert it into Destination table or if existing row has been modified, update the same row.

New Rows `---ISNULL(Dest_EmpId)`

Changed Rows `(Id !=Dest_EmpId)||ISNULL(admin)`

I have an existing  column(admin) which is null and has been updated with  a value (`20200901`).  the conditional split  is not able to evaluate it correctly, hence the unchanged row doesn't get updated.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an OR condition on the IFF expression. With limited knowledge of the data that you are using and the design of the package in general, I would say that this is the only plausible explanation. Did you try changing the OR to AND and see if that helped?